# Angular 2. Main layout for all routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to create layout for my app. So, I use the following routes:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'contact',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren : 'app/contact/contact.module#ContactModule'
      }
    ]
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

As you can see I use `MainLayoutComponent` for layout. And, when my application starts I want to redirect to `contact` path.

The layout contains navigation and `router-outlet`:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <nav>Navigation content</nav>
    <div class="container"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
  `,
})
```

This is template in `ContactComponent`:
`<h2>Contact Component</h2>`

The problem is, when app is run I see `Contact Component` message, but I don't see navigation. But, if I open `localhost:3000/contact` then I see navigation and  `Contact Component` message. What am I missing?

This is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/3zoQbtk4xfjXdAuiiWGC?p=preview). You can check,  I creaed `Go to Contact` button to redirect to `/contact` url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you've done it on purpose... but you seem to have really over-complicated things. You can easily achieve what you're trying to do with a much simpler structure and by putting the navigation in your main component:

https://plnkr.co/edit/pCQvJ3PwO0nMPxRvWR1o?p=preview

Anyway - the reason your plunker isn't doing what you expect is because in your contact module you've defined some routing as well:

```
    { path: '', component: ContactComponent }
```

I removed the contact routing from the contact component and now it seems to be working:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ ],
  declarations: [ ContactComponent ],
  providers:    [ ]
})
export class ContactModule { }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Rwl5Hw83LfkLmG4wF3oK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answer, well I make it in that way for better customizing. If I need other layout I will just create it. For example, for login/register page.

Comment: But, I can't understand why route inside ContactModule handle root url, I register this route with `forChild` method. Could you explain me?

Comment: It's because the routes declared with forChild get merged in to the routes declared with forRoot. In your case you declare the route:       {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'contact',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'contact',
        loadChildren : 'app/contact/contact.module#ContactModule'
      } in the forRoot and then you declare     { path: '', component: ContactComponent }
 in the for child. This effectively overwrites {
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'contact',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      } which is why your nav doesn't show up

Comment: the forChild would be intented for situations where you need to extend the available routes ie: {path: "contact/:id", ... }, {path: "contact/all", ...} might be some routes you would declare in your contact routing module.

Comment: Actually, I have found the real error, the error is importing ContactModule into AppModule. If I delete it then all works fine.